# Using submit_form() from rvest package returns a form which is not updated

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape data from a website after entering information into a form using the `rvest` package (version 0.3.1) in R (version 3.3.0).  Below is my code:

```
# Load Packages
library(rvest)

# Specify URL
url <- "http://www.cocorahs.org/ViewData/ListDailyPrecipReports.aspx"
cocorahs <- html_session(url)

# Grab Initial Form
#  Form is filled in stages. Here, only do country and date
form.unfilled <- cocorahs %>% html_node("form") %>% html_form()
form.filled <- form.unfilled %>% 
  set_values("frmPrecipReportSearch:ucStateCountyFilter:ddlCountry" = "840",
             "frmPrecipReportSearch_ucDateRangeFilter_dcStartDate" = "6/15/2016",
             "frmPrecipReportSearch_ucDateRangeFilter_dcEndDate" = "6/15/2016")

submit_form(cocorahs, form.filled,
            submit="frmPrecipReportSearch:btnSearch") %>%
  html_node("form") %>% html_form()
```

I was expecting the result to display the updated form; while the Country updated to the USA, the date range reverts back to the default (date of access).  What am I missing to ensure the form updates that particular field?

Answer (score 1):

I think you made an error in

```
"frmPrecipReportSearch:ucStateCountyFilter:ddlCountry" = "840"
```

You entered a numeric value when a country name was required.

See the code below

```
# Load Packages
library(rvest)

# Specify URL
url <- "http://www.cocorahs.org/ViewData/ListDailyPrecipReports.aspx"
cocorahs <- html_session(url)

# Grab Initial Form
#  Form is filled in stages. Here, only do country and date
form.unfilled <- cocorahs %>% html_node("form") %>% html_form()
form.filled <- form.unfilled %>%
set_values("frmPrecipReportSearch:ucStationTextFieldsFilter:tbTextFieldValue" = "840",
         "frmPrecipReportSearch_ucDateRangeFilter_dcStartDate" = "6/15/2016",
         "frmPrecipReportSearch_ucDateRangeFilter_dcEndDate" = "6/15/2016")

# submit the form and save as a new session
session <- submit_form(cocorahs, form.filled) 

# look for a table in the nodes
table <- session %>% html_nodes("table")

# The table you want
table[[7]] %>% html_table()
```