# How do I find html_node on search form?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a list of names (first name, last name, and date-of-birth) that I need to search the Fulton County Georgia (USA) Jail website to determine if a person is in or released from jail.

The website is http://justice.fultoncountyga.gov/PAJailManager/JailingSearch.aspx?ID=400

The site requires you enter a last name and first name, then it gives you a list of results.

I have found some stackoverflow posts that have given me some direction, but I'm still struggling to figure this out. I"m using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868709/using-submit-form-from-rvest-package-returns-a-form-which-is-not-updated) as and example to follow. I am using SelectorGaget to help figure out the CSS tags.

Here is the code I have so far. Right now I can't figure out what `html_node` to use.

```
library(rvest)

# Specify URL
fc.url <- "http://justice.fultoncountyga.gov/PAJailManager/JailingSearch.aspx?ID=400"

# start session
jail <- html_session(fc.url)

# Grab initial form
form.unfilled <- jail %>% html_node("form")

form.unfilled
```

The result I get from `form.unfilled` is `{xml_missing} <NA>` which I know isn't right.

I think if I can figure out the `html_node` value, I can proceed to using `set_values` and `submit_form`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears on the initial call the webpage opens onto "http://justice.fultoncountyga.gov/PAJailManager/default.aspx".  Once the session is started you should be able to jump to the search page:

```
library(rvest)

# Specify URL
fc.url <- "http://justice.fultoncountyga.gov/PAJailManager/JailingSearch.aspx?ID=400"

# start session
jail <- html_session("http://justice.fultoncountyga.gov/PAJailManager/default.aspx")
#jump to search page
jail2 <- jail %>% jump_to("http://justice.fultoncountyga.gov/PAJailManager/JailingSearch.aspx?ID=400")

#list the form's fields
html_form(jail2)[[1]]

# Grab initial form
form.unfilled <- jail2 %>% html_node("form")
```

*Note:* Verify that your actions are within the terms of service for the website.  Many sites do have policy against **scraping**.

Comment: Thanks. This got me to the next step. I'll post another question for the hurtle. Once I submit the form with some name values, I get a "An error occurred while processing your request" message.

Comment: @JohnMoses,  `submit_form` may not be the correct method.  One may have to try the `POST` method.  This is getting beyond my skill level, trying posting a new question with your "working" code and see if some else has more experience.

Answer (score 1):

The website relies heavily on Javascript to render itself. When opening the link you provided in a fresh browser instance, you get redirected to `http://justice.fultoncountyga.gov/PAJailManager/default.aspx`, where you have to click the "Jail Records" link. This executes a bit a Javascript, to send you to the page with the form.

`rvest` is unable to execute arbitrary Javascript. You might have to look at `RSelenium`. `Selenium` basically remote-controls a browser (for example Firefox or Chrome), which executes the Javascript as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dave2e.

Here is the code that works. This questions is answered (but I'll post another one because I'm not getting a table of data as a result.)

*Note: I cannot find any Terms of Service on this site that I'm querying*

```
library(rvest)

# start session
jail <- html_session("http://justice.fultoncountyga.gov/PAJailManager/default.aspx")
#jump to search page
jail2 <- jail %>% jump_to("http://justice.fultoncountyga.gov/PAJailManager/JailingSearch.aspx?ID=400")

#list the form's fields
html_form(jail2)[[1]]


# Grab initial form
form.unfilled <- jail2 %>% html_node("form") %>% html_form()

form.unfilled

#name values
lname <- "DOE"
fname <- "JOHN"

# Fille the form with name values
form.filled <- form.unfilled %>% 
        set_values("LastName" = lname,
                   "FirstName" = fname)

#Submit form
r <- submit_form(jail2, form.filled,
            submit = "SearchSubmit")

#grab tables from submitted form
table <- r %>% html_nodes("table")

#grab a table with some data
table[[5]] %>% html_table()

# resulting text in this table:
# " An error occurred while processing your request.Please contact your system administrator."
```