# How to troubleshoot an error after submit_form using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

This a continuation of my initial [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61819491/how-do-i-find-html-node-on-search-form) about webscraping a jail website.

*Note: I cannot find any Terms of Service on the below website prohibiting scraping.*

The end result I'm looking for is to extract the html table that results from a name search into a dataframe in R.

I've made some progress of getting to an html_session in R and entering search terms using `set_values` and `submit_form`, however the table that results after I submit the form gives me a message that says "An error occurred while processing your request..."

I can't isolate where the error is in submitting the form. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Code below:

```
## scrape Fulton County Jail using rvest



library(rvest)

# Specify URL
#fc.url <- "http://justice.fultoncountyga.gov/PAJailManager/JailingSearch.aspx?ID=400"

# start session
jail <- html_session("http://justice.fultoncountyga.gov/PAJailManager/default.aspx")
#jump to search page
jail2 <- jail %>% jump_to("http://justice.fultoncountyga.gov/PAJailManager/JailingSearch.aspx?ID=400")

#list the form's fields
html_form(jail2)[[1]]


# Grab initial form
form.unfilled <- jail2 %>% html_node("form") %>% html_form()

form.unfilled

#name values
lname <- "DOE"
fname <- "JOHN"

# Fille the form with name values
form.filled <- form.unfilled %>% 
        set_values("LastName" = lname,
                   "FirstName" = fname)

#Submit form
r <- submit_form(jail2, form.filled,
            submit = "SearchSubmit")

#grab tables from submitted form
table <- r %>% html_nodes("table")

#grab a table with some data
table[[5]] %>% html_table()

# resulting text in this table:
# " An error occurred while processing your request.Please contact your system administrator."
```