# Getting 504 Error when trying to log-in using Rvest form

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to login to a site that has a paywall.  The site I  need to access is: "https://razzball.com/", and the login button on the website takes me to this page to login "https://razzball.com/wp-login.php".

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# razzball 

razzball_id = Sys.getenv("razzball_id")
razzball_password = Sys.getenv("razzball_password")

# Open Session on Base Login Page
my_session <- rvest::session("https://razzball.com/wp-login.php")
unfilled_forms <- rvest::html_form(my_session)
login_form <- unfilled_forms[[1]]
filled_form <- rvest::html_form_set(login_form, 
                                    log = razzball_id, 
                                    pwd = razzball_password) # fill the form
login_session <- rvest::session_submit(my_session, filled_form, submit = "wp-submit")
#> Warning in session_set_response(x, resp): Gateway Timeout (HTTP 504).
```

I can confirm that the password, and user name are correct.  I'm not sure why I am getting an error.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: Try using `set_values` to fill form and instead of `log` use `"log"`. Further reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868709/using-submit-form-from-rvest-package-returns-a-form-which-is-not-updated

Comment: That unfortunately didn't work.